# hide fieldset elements on page load or when a radio button option is already selected

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to **hide** fieldset elements on page load when the radio button 'No' is already checked and when 'yes' is checked the fieldset **should appear**. Currently, the fieldset hides if the user checks 'No' and/or shows if user checks 'Yes'. But i want the fieldset to be hidden on page load or if 'No' is already checked, and the fieldset and its contents should be displayed once 'Yes' is checked.

**hide_show_field.js**

```
function ToggleDisplay(Section, boolHide) {
    if (boolHide) {
        Section.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        Section.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function disableElement(element, boolHide)
{
    var input = document.getElementById(element).getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            input[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
}

function hideShowElement(CurrentSection, OtherSection, DisableSection)
{
    var sectionVal = CurrentSection.value;
        if (sectionVal == 'No') {
            ToggleDisplay(OtherSection, true);
            disableElement(DisableSection, "true");
        }
        else {
            ToggleDisplay(OtherSection, false);
            disableElement(DisableSection, "false");
        }
}
```

---

**form.php**

```
<p class="text">
            <label for="Transferred">Transferred</label>
            <input type="radio" name="transferred" value="Yes" onchange="hideShowElement(this, mydiv, 'optionGroup');">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="transferred" value="No" onchange="hideShowElement(this, mydiv, 'optionGroup');">No
        </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

<fieldset class="group" id="optionGroup">
    <legend>Transfer</legend>
    <div id="mydiv">
    <div class="col">
        <p class="text">
            <label for="Transferred To">Transferred To</label>
            <select name="transferTo">
                <option value="Select Station"></option>
                <?php include('php/selectlocation.php'); ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p class="text">
            <label for="Date Transferred">Date Transferred</label>
            <input type="date" name="dateTransferredTo" id="datepicker1" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" >
        </p>         
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p class="text">
            <label for="Transferred From">Transferred From</label>
            <select name="transferFrom" >
                <option value="0"></option>
                <?php include('php/selectlocation.php'); ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p class="text">
            <label for="Date Transferred">Date Transferred</label>
            <input type="date" name="dateTransferredFrom" id="datepicker2" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" >
        </p>
        <p class="text">
            <label for="Rank Transferred With">Rank Transferred With</label>
            <select name="rankTransferredWith">
                <option value="0"></option>
                <?php include('php/selectranks.php'); ?>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Could someone provide some assistance please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to set the input for the "no" checked="true" in the php...
But the way you activate your js it will probably not work. It is better to select those elements in the js code and check if they are selected. You probably need to use an anonymous function, to make sure everything works well...

```
(function () {
     if (radio.checked) {
        //hide or show
     }
}()):
```